# Polygon locations from string?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a string containg locations for a polygon. My problem is, that i cannot figure out how i convert this string, back to lat lng objects, that i can use, to plot the polygon onto a google map.

This is my data

```
var geometry = "(55.595892233825545, 12.663964033126831),(55.595486072831385, 12.66323447227478),(55.5953284569849, 12.665669918060303),(55.59621352237994, 12.664951086044312)"
var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
   paths: geometry,
   strokeColor: '#FF0000',
   strokeOpacity: 0.8,
   strokeWeight: 2,
   fillColor: '#FF0000',
   fillOpacity: 0.35
});
```

But obviously, that does not work.
i have tried to find a function, to convert my string back to locations objects, but without luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the string into [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLng) objects, use those for the path of the [google.maps.Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Polygon).

```
var geometry = "(55.595892233825545, 12.663964033126831),(55.595486072831385, 12.66323447227478),(55.5953284569849, 12.665669918060303),(55.59621352237994, 12.664951086044312)";
// Get rid of outside ().
geometry = geometry.substring(1, geometry.length - 1); 
// remove extra spaces
var coordStr = geometry.replace(/,\s/g,","); 
var coordsArray = coordStr.split("),(");
var path = [];
for (var i=0; i<coordsArray.length;i++) {
   var coords = coordsArray[i].split(",");
   var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(
   parseFloat(coords[0]),
   parseFloat(coords[1]));
   path.push(pt);
}
var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
   paths: path,
   strokeColor: '#FF0000',
   strokeOpacity: 0.8,
   strokeWeight: 2,
   fillColor: '#FF0000',
   fillOpacity: 0.35
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/25zd3z20/11/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var geometry = "(55.595892233825545, 12.663964033126831),(55.595486072831385, 12.66323447227478),(55.5953284569849, 12.665669918060303),(55.59621352237994, 12.664951086044312)";
  // Get rid of outside ().
  geometry = geometry.substring(1, geometry.length - 1);
  // remove extra spaces
  var coordStr = geometry.replace(/,\s/g, ",");
  var coordsArray = coordStr.split("),(");
  var path = [];
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < coordsArray.length; i++) {
    var coords = coordsArray[i].split(",");
    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(
      parseFloat(coords[0]),
      parseFloat(coords[1]));
    path.push(pt);
    bounds.extend(pt)
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: path,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps, according to this [information](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple).

The solution gets all numbers and reassembles them to an array with point objects.

```js
function getCoords(string) {
    var coords = [];
    string.match(/[\d.]+/g).map(Number).forEach(function (a, i) {
        if (i % 2) {
            coords[coords.length - 1].lng = a;
        } else {
            coords.push({ lat: a });
        }
    });
    return coords;
}

var geometry = "(55.595892233825545, 12.663964033126831),(55.595486072831385, 12.66323447227478),(55.5953284569849, 12.665669918060303),(55.59621352237994, 12.664951086044312)",
    coords = getCoords(geometry),
    polygon = /* new google.maps.Polygon( */ {
        paths: coords,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    } /* ) */;

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(polygon, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: The format looks right, but it does not look like it gets converted to an array. "not an array" is the error, and when printed out, its also as a string. Other than that, it looks spot on :)

Comment: hm, for me, the result looks like an array.

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry, The cords are, but not the JSON.stringify, which i had copied also.

Removing that helped, but now this error comes: http://screencast.com/t/iRgRbJjzuEe

Comment: You helped alot, thank you :) I added "if (string) {..}" arround the string.match. That made the error go away, but no polygon are drawn to the map. Wierd.

Answer (score 0):

**geocodezip** is right,

the point is parsing the string to an array of google.maps.LatLng,
and use it as paths in polygon option while you create it.

if you need to load the points in a dynamic logic, you can set the path later.

```
    var oNewPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon(polygonOptions);
    oNewPolygon.setMap(this.m_oMap);
    /*... ... ....
    'dynamic logics of loading polygon path
    'and parsing the string to polygonpaths(array of google.maps.LatLng)
    .......... draw the map.........*/
    oNewPolygon.setPaths(polygonpaths);
```